# Is there a better way to write this navigation statement?

Tags: jquery

I know this is a redundant way to write these rules so I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way to write it. Thanks!

```
$('.nav li a').eq(0).click(function() {

    $('.nav li a').eq(0).addClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(1).removeClass("active"); 
    $('.nav li a').eq(2).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(3).removeClass("active");

});
$('.nav li a').eq(1).click(function() {

    $('.nav li a').eq(0).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(1).addClass("active");    
    $('.nav li a').eq(2).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(3).removeClass("active");

});
$('.nav li a').eq(2).click(function() {

    $('.nav li a').eq(0).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(1).removeClass("active"); 
    $('.nav li a').eq(2).addClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(3).removeClass("active");

});
$('.nav li a').eq(3).click(function() {

    $('.nav li a').eq(0).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(1).removeClass("active"); 
    $('.nav li a').eq(2).removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li a').eq(3).addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: Could you show us your markup as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of code which can be condensed. Try this:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function()
{
  $('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd move the class to the `<li>`, like this:

```
$('.nav li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

If you just changing the styling to match, for example:

```
li.active a { /* styles */ }
```

...then it's much simpler overall to have the `click` handler on the `<li>` elements, since *those* are the set you're dealing with.  There's also the more efficient [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method:

```
$('.nav').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: +1 If OP wants to disable the click on the `.active` element, it would be trivial with the `.delegate()` version.

Comment: @patrick - another trivial change I like this this approach is the easy ability to change `.addClass()` to `.toggleClass()` if you want to be able to "deactivate" as well, not sure if it matters in this case or not.

Comment: Nick your first example is not removing the classes.

Comment: @JJNold - Is the class moved to the `<li>`, like I noted above, or starting on the `<a>` still?

Comment: @Nick the class is on the anchor element.

Comment: @JJNold - can you move it to the `<li>` to simplify things overall?  The answer is premised on that, it would look like this otherwise: `$('.nav li a').click(function() { $(this).addClass("active").parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active"); });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav li a').bind('click', function() {
    $('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $('.nav li a.active').removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
  $('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Removes the `active` class from each a and then adds it to the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about what your document looks like, but this is what I might do:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $('.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```